# How can I get `prettier` to properly format perm set XML files with `flowAccess`?

Tags: metadata, vs-code, prettier

Our team is working with mock permission sets in our project for testing features. We have triggers to apply `prettier` when saving or committing files, and it's been breaking our perm set metadata files.

For example, we have these tags in one of our perm set metadata files:

```
<flowAccesses>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <flow>Mock_Object_Link_Flow</flow>
</flowAccesses>
```

Adding a carriage return anywhere (just to edit the file and cause the saving to trigger `prettier`) changes the above to the following:

```
<flowAccesses>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <flow>
Mock_Object_Link_Flow;
    </flow>
</flowAccesses>
```

At this point the source tracking sees that there's a change and if we try to deploy to our sandbox or scratch org we get errors.

We currently work around this by correcting the file outside of VS Code or by committing with the `--no-verify` flag.

For reference, here are the contents of our `.prettierrc`:

```
**/staticresources/**
.sfdx
```

and `.prettierignore`:

```
{
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "singleQuote": true,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": "**/lwc/**/*.html",
            "options": { "parser": "lwc" }
        },
        {
            "files": "*.{cmp,page,component}",
            "options": { "parser": "html" }
        }
    ]
}
```

What is causing this and how can we fix it?

Comment: Have you tried updating your `.prettierignore` file?

Comment: @NickC, I don't know what update might affect this, but I've included the contents of our `prettier` config files above. `prettier` famously offers few customization options, and I don't see which one available for `prettier` itself, nor for the XML parser (https://github.com/prettier/plugin-xml) that would solve this. Adding `**/*.xml` to `.prettierignore` does prevent parsing XML files and "fixes" the problem, but we _do_ want XML properly parsed by `prettier`. So that's at least a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's another prettier plugin that works with something called "flow." I *think* it's something to do with the [Flow Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-parser), but am not sure. I do see a `parser-flow.mjs`n file within the `prettier` package.

Regardless, the `<flow>` tag in the XML seems to be getting messed up by this. The [solution](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-xml/issues/751#issuecomment-1900850165) is to add `"embeddedLanguageFormatting": "off"` to `.prettierrc`.